# Reading a file's details in nodejs, regardless of file type

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I'm currently working on a nwjs (formerly node-webkit) application for organizing all files in a directory, regardless of type. The end goal will allow me to place all files in alphabetical folders, based on a number of file properties.

An example would be a folder that contains three files, let's say an MP3, a WAV file, and a .odt file. I'm needing to read some arbitrary metadata off of each of these files so I can perform a "best guess" as to where I should organize the file.

I found a few npm packages for reading metadata from individual types of files (https://github.com/gomfunkel/node-exif for JPEGS, https://github.com/43081j/id3 for MP3 tags), but nothing prebuilt for this particular usage.

If I were to write my own, is there anything about the FS that's built into nodejs that would help?

Comment: Regardless of file type? No. You need to know something about a file format in order to read its data. You need to know that JPEGs have a width in the first place, then you need to know how it is encoded in the file, in order to read it. This means that for each kind of metadata, someone has to program a reader library. It might be one huge one (not sure that exists), or a bunch of tiny ones, but a general one is as impossible as a machine that can cook every meal ever all by itself without being provided a recipe or an ingredient list.

Comment: You bring up some valid points. Thanks for your input.

Comment: ExifTool (http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) comes close to doing what you want.  It will recognize and extract metadata from all the file types you mentioned, and more.  The only problem is that it is a Perl script.

Answer (score 0):

There is a binding to libmagic (what the `file` command uses) for node called [`mmmagic`](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic). With it you can scan files and obtain the "best guess" mime type for each.

From there it's a matter of comparing the detected mime type against a list of mime types that are valid for each of your subdirectories.